# Generate a random matrix with a condition on its eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, random, eigenvalues

I can generate Radom matrices using

```
mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}];
```

But how can I generate the `mat` matrix so that the difference between its eigenvalues be larger than a value~(`val`), i.e., imposing `Eigenvalues[mat][[2]] - Eigenvalues[mat][[1]]>val`?

Comment: Generate a random set of eigenvalues that have the property you want, stuff them into a diagonal matrix, and then perform a similarity transformation on that diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Shasa You are looking for matrix with only real eigenvalues?

Comment: @J.M. it works! Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  Yes and the other suggestion solved the problem. Thank for your time.

Comment: If you were able to write code that implements my suggestion, you could consider answering your own question. ;)